# Difference between the two approaches in styling the host element dynamically in Angular

Tags: angular

According to the official document and other articles, Angular provides a couple of ways to style the host element.

via:

- `:host` selector in `.css` file
- `@HostBinding`
- `Renderer2`

With the `:host` selector, I get to declare some static styles.

What about changing the style of the host element dynamically?
Say, I want to change the `display` state of the host element upon an event:

**Using `@HostBinding`**

```
export class UseHostBindingComponent {
  @HostBinding('style.display') display: string;

  // Change the display state of the host element
  onClick(): void {
    this.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

**Using `Renderer2`**

```
export class UseRenderer2Component {
  constructor(
    private renderer: Renderer2,
    private el: ElementRef
  ) {}

  // Change the display state of the host element
  onClick(): void {
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'display', 'none');
  }
}
```

Both approaches work but I just wonder the difference between them. Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `Renderer2` you manually update view, just in time when you need.

With `HostBinding` you tell Angular check binded property every time when Change Detection will be called and update View if value changed. So if Change Detection will be not called for your component, View will not update.

Comment: I have not done any performance tests, so I can not say which one is more effective. I can assume that the method with `Renerer2` is more efficient because we use a more lower-level API and skip unnecessary checks and wrappers. But I think the differance is minor.

Comment: Awesome! So `[style.someStyleProperty]`(aka `style binding`) also works like the `HostBinding`, telling Angular to apply it on the next check?

Comment: Yes, `[style.someStyleProperty]` it's binding inside of templates, Angular check/update templates only by Change Detection run.